# Does Mahout need to be installed on the Hadoop's master node?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

That's a dumb question, but somebody has to ask it.

I've tried running Mahout locally, which worked. Now, I wanna the work to be performed by a remote cluster, not my local machine.

So, should I deploy the Mahout code on Hadoop machines or I can still make Mahout on my local machine interface remotely with Hadoop?

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't install Hadoop programs on the Hadoop workers yourself. That would be a nightmare to maintain. Hadoop does it for you when you provide it the JAR file with all code via `hadoop jar`.

What runs on your local machine, when you run Mahout or anything else Hadoop-based, is a client program that uses Hadoop code to send info to a cluster to start work. That cluster might be local, or remote -- makes no difference to how you run the client, just what the client talks to.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! 
Then how do I specify paths if mahout and hadoop reside on different machines, e.g. in $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $MAHOUT_HOME/core/target/mahout-core-<VERSION>-job.jar org.apache.mahout.df.tools.Describe -p testdata/glass.data -f testdata/glass.info -d I 9 N L?

Comment: Yeah looks about right. You specify a local path, local to the client program. Hadoop manages uploading it to the HDFS cluster where everything can access it.